# GraphQL: Add @client Directive Only In Local Development Mode

Tags: javascript, graphql

I'm new to GraphQL. I'm currently using client-side defaults and the @client directive in my queries to fetch the data locally.
Is there a way to work in local state in development environment and to disable this mode in production? 
As in conditionally adding the @client directive?

Comment: You can use the `@skip` directive to skip any particular field, including `@client` ones. You can use the `skip` property of a `Query` component to not run an entire query. You can't disable state management in total though. It's not clear why you would want to do that though.

Comment: @Daniel Rearden I'm using local state management (@client defaults) for testing and for presenting a serverless demo mode. It would be convenient to be able to switch from demo mode to production mode, which doesn't utilize any client defaults.